# JQuery Ajax 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm utilizing the jquery library to make an ajax call to a php file. Everything was working fine when the path was relative like this:

```
url:"fetch_term_grades.php",
```

But when I change the path like this:

```
url:"includes/ajax/fetch_term_grades.php",
```

I'm getting this error from the console:

```
jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/SchoolMate/includes/ajax/fetch_term_grades.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

[image]

This is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"includes/ajax/fetch_term_grades.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{"term":term},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);               
            $('#dataTable').DataTable();
            //$('table').attr('id', 'dataTable');  
        }

      });
```

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error means "Server Error". Take a look at your server side. Some error log should give to you more information about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url:"includes/ajax/fetch_term_grades.php"`

this is still a relative path as I understand. Try with `/` at the beginning like `/` + actual path to that script in your filesystem. Maybe it is `url:"/includes/ajax/fetch_term_grades.php"`

Comment: thanks. updated my post already.  Did add    /    at the beginning but I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: what is written in the logs of the server? Are you sure that fetch_term_grades.php doesn't cause that error? Can you access that script via  http://localhost/SchoolMate/includes/ajax/fetch_term_grades.php?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu and using apache. How do I view the server logs?

Comment: it depends on your exact configuration. Browse within `/var/log` folder or check the config file.

Comment: thanks so much for the insight on the log file. The problem came from the script itself, I was referencing other file within the script and the path to those files were wrong. Got it working now. Thanks once again.

Comment: glad to hear that your problem is gone :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which location you are calling that script from. In your case the file that calls the scripts is located under the same folder which is includes/ajax/fetch_term_grades.php. If you want to call it using this url includes/ajax/fetch_term_grades.php you should put two layers up, ie: it should be side by side with the includes folder.

Comment: the file that calls the script is within the root folder.        And the sript is within this folders/folders (includes/ajax/). If I'm right I can say the script is two(2) levels down the root folder.

Comment: Is the file that calls the script is on the same level with the includes folder?

Comment: If you're asking if they are both in the same root folder then the answer is yes.